AVR microcontroller dead after trying to enter debugging session
this is already the second time I encounter this strange problem:
I am using an AVR microcontroller with microchip studio.
I wanted to enter a debugging session with "Start debugging and break".
I selected my tool, the Atmel ICE, toggled the target power, clicked "OK" and since then my chip cannot be programmed. Neither can I reset the fuses, nor can I reprogram the chip.
It kinda turned into a brick.
I used this time an ATMega88PA and I had a similar problem with an ATtiny85.
This is the error message I get from microchip studio when I try to enter programming mode:
Failed to enter programming mode. ispEnterProgMode: Error status received: Got 0xc0, expected 0x00 (Command has failed to execute on the tool)
Unable to enter programming mode. Verify device selection, interface settings, target power, security bit, and connections to the target device.

Timestamp:  2024-12-23 16:19:42.666
Severity:       ERROR
ComponentId:    20100
StatusCode: 1
ModuleName: TCF (TCF command: Device:startSession failed.)
Failed to enter programming mode. ispEnterProgMode: Error status received: Got 0xc0, expected 0x00 (Command has failed to execute on the tool)

And I get a pretty similar message when I try to reenter debug mode.
What is the problem and how can I solve it?
This is getting really annoying since this is the second time this happened again...

Are you using genuine programming interface/tools? The cloned ones are hit and miss quality-wise. Some work great, some don’t quite.

Try this https://microchip.my.site.com/s/article/ATmega328P-XMINI---Failed-to-enter-programming-mode  https://youtu.be/6axdc4hIy60?si=AU-eHnLXBn-SkAFY&t=196

I am using the Atmel ICE.
I tried the same procedure as in the video, sadly did not work.
I get the following error message:
"Failed to enable DW: Failed to enter programming mode. iseEnterProgMode: Error status received: Got 0xc0, expected 0x00 (Command has failed to execute on the tool)"
Strange thing is, debugging did work in the past, and now for some reason it does not.
